# How to mock a component with some attach properties

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, jestjs, mocking

im using jest to write some test case for my app

Let's say there is a library name `@library`, which i use a component name `Input`

in my App

```
import {Input} from '@library';

const App = () => {
    return <Input size={Input.SIZE.md} />
}
```

The source code of Input in library assuming looks something like this

```
const Input = () => { // some code }

Input.SIZE = {
  md: 'md',
  lg: 'lg'
}

export {Input};
```

so now in my test case, i want to mock the Input module, lets say to become

```
<div data-testid='mock-input' />
```

When i do this,

```
jest.mock('@library', () => {
  return {
    Input: () => <div data-testid='mock-input' />
  }
})
```

It will throw errors because it says it missing SIZE in the mocked Input.

1. But what should be the correct syntax now ? When I only want to change the rendering part of Input, but want to keep all attached values (like SIZE)
2. What if i only want to change the Input component to mock div for only 1 test case in the file, not all test cases, how to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Mocking Partials](https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-functions#mocking-partials). Copy all static properties from the original function component to the mock function component.

E.g.

`library.jsx`:

```
const Input = () => <div>original input</div>;

Input.SIZE = {
  md: 'md',
  lg: 'lg',
};

export { Input };
```

`index.test.jsx`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import { Input } from './library';

jest.mock('./library', () => {
  const originalLibrary = jest.requireActual('./library');
  const InputMock = () => <div data-testid="mock-input" />;
  Object.assign(InputMock, originalLibrary.Input);
  return {
    Input: InputMock,
  };
});

describe('76214614', () => {
  test('should pass', () => {
    const { asFragment } = render(<Input />);
    expect(Input.SIZE).toEqual({ md: 'md', lg: 'lg' });
    expect(asFragment().firstChild).toMatchInlineSnapshot(`
      <div
        data-testid="mock-input"
      />
    `);
  });
});
```

Test result:

```bash
 PASS  stackoverflow/76214614/index.test.jsx (26.421 s)
  76214614
    ✓ should pass (49 ms)

 › 1 snapshot written.
Snapshot Summary
 › 1 snapshot written from 1 test suite.

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   1 written, 1 total
Time:        27.334 s
```

Comment: hi , thanks for your good solution, it works . However, can i ask what if i only want to mock the Input component for 1 test case only, how can i write it ? . Currently your jest.mock solution will apply to all test case in this file